# Leaflet Map not appears at all

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, openstreetmap

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <title>BookSmart</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.5/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.5/leaflet.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

</head>

<body>
    <h1>BookSmart</h1>

    <p>Here's a new BookSmart</p> 

  <div class="map-wrap">
    <div id="map" style="height: 440px; width: 1325px; border: 1px solid #AAA;"></div>
        </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Category</button>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" size="192" placeholder="Search a desired services...">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Search!</button>
                </span>
             </span>
         </div>
     </div>



    <script>
        var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '$copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            maxZoom: 18
        }).addTo(map);.

    </script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    map.locate({setView: true ,maxZoom: 16});

    function onLocationFound(e) {
        var radius = e.accuracy / 2;

        L.marker(e.latlng, radius).addTo(map);
            .bindPopup("You are within " + radius + " meters from this point").openPopup();

        L.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(map);
    }

    map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);

    function onLocationError(e) {
        alert(e.message);
    }

    map.on('locationerror', onLocationError);


    </script>

    <script type='text/javascript' src="leaflet/leafletembed.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="maps/marker.json"></script>


    <script type='text/javascript' src="../marker/marker.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="../map/maps.js"></script>


 </body>
```

I did test almost everything. When I make just a simple code containing only div id and tile layer, it did works but when i start to customize the code to become more interactive, nothing appears. This is what i get almost all of the time

[This is the only result get. Could someone help me on this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8gW7.png)

Comment: What errors are in the console?

Answer (score 3):

You have several syntax errors in your first inline `script` block:

- Missing comma (`,`) after the attribution string.
- Extra dot (`.`) at the end of the tileLayer statement (after `addTo(map);.`)

And in the next inline `script` block:

- Extra semicolon (`;`) at the end of marker statement first line but before the bindPopup (`addTo(map);.bindPopup`)

As suggested by @Jason, the browser console is one of the first debugging tool (hit F12 on most browsers to open the developers panel).

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll refixed it. But, i don't have to customize all the code and save it in index.html right? I can create file for popup(geojson) and marker.

Comment: There are several problem within my leaflet project including geolocation, fetching marker from database and popup info through click of button. Could anyone help me here? Any help will be an extreme pleasure

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean, but yes, your code can be externalized in a dedicated JS file that you import through a `script` tag with `src` attribute like any other JS file. By the way, I am not sure either what you intend to do with your `maps/marker.json` file. If it is a correct JSON file, it will do nothing if you just import it through a `script` tag. You have to load it through an AJAX-like request so that you can parse its content.

Comment: As for your next comment, if you cannot debug it yourself, you can post more questions (one per issue would be best) with associated code. A very good practice is to reproduce your issue online (e.g. on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/18/)) so that people can directly modify your code and provide you with a working solution.

Comment: Cool @ghybs and others. Thanks a lot for helping me. There's already a lot of code. Btw, regarding the index.html that i recently posted, do i have to insert window.onLoad() function as well for initialization

Comment: As for placing your code in a page load callback, there is indeed a good practice to rather use the [`DOMContentLoaded` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded). That being said, you do not necessarily need that either: as long as the nodes that you manipulate are up of your script, you are already good.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. The map is up and running but no marker appears. Btw, could i set setview of the whole map to true rather placing the regional coordinates so that when user open the map, it shows their location. Could someone help me on this? Appreciate in advance

Comment: Feel free to open new questions for your next issues.